# AppleIDが使えない状態で電話帳をバックアップしたい

Tags: iphone

iPhoneでフィッシング詐欺にあいました。
詳細は簡潔にさせていただきます。
本物と見分けのつかないポップアップによるパスワード入力が原因です。
Apple IDに紐づいた「信頼できる電話番号」が書き換えられています。
つまりパスワードのリセット、再設定や、新規AppleIDの作成もできない状態です。

Appleサポートとやり取りして相談しました。必要な書類をAppleに画像添付で送っています。Appleより「ロック解除しました」という通知が来ればiPhoneを初期化できます。

そこで問題が電話帳のバックアップです。Line等はアプリごとにできるようですし、
他のアプリは再度入れなおせば済むだけです。Apple IDが現在使えず、次回は全くこれまでと関連のないApple IDを作成することになるので機種変更の時のようにiCloudから取り出すことが出来ません。当然ですが、Apple IDに紐づいたiCoudにもアクセスが出来ない状態です。ガラケー⇒iPhoneに替える場合は赤外線を使って電話帳や端末内の画像等へ移行が出来るようですが、今回のケースとは全く異なりキャリアに相談しても難しいと思います。

現状、端末を使って出来ることは「連絡先」アプリから「連絡先を送信」してLineやGmail等に送信するしかないようです。電話帳に数百件登録してあるのですが、これは１件、１件しか送信出来ません。なので数百件分のメールを送信することになります。あとは自分で紙なり、エクセルなりに全て手作業で書き写すかです。
作業量が膨大過ぎます。

Apple MusicでサブスクリプションしていますのでiTunesは利用用途がなくＰＣに入れていません。
初期化する際にはパソコンと接続をしiTuneを使わなければならないそうです。

本題ですが、現状Apple IDが使えないため、iCloudにアクセスできず、データ移行のアプリの類をAppStoreから入れる事が出来ません。

このような状況でパソコン等を使い電話帳をUSBなりCloudなどに保存しておき、初期化後の端末に入れなおす方法はありますか？

もし、何らかの方法をご存知でしたら方法を教えて下さい。
宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: 電話帳が iCloud に同期してあれば、元々電話帳は iCloud にバックアップされている（データの本体は iCloud 側に残っている）はずですが、同期していなかったということでしょうか？

Comment: iCloudにはバックアップされていると思いますが、現状Apple IDを無効にしている状態のためAppleIDに紐づいているiCloudにはアクセスできない状態です。

Comment: アカウントのロックが解除されれば、元通りに同期され直すだけではないでしょうか？ そもそも iPhone を初期化する必要はあるのですか？

Comment: アカウントが第三者に乗っ取られている状態です。Appleより現在のアカウントは無効にされています。信頼できる電話番号も変更されているためApple IDの新規作成やパスワードのリセット、再設定も出来ない状態です。Appleよりロック解除された後は初期化して全く違うApple IDで設定しなおさなければなりません

Answer (score 1, accepted):

少し調べた程度で実際に試したわけではありませんが、以下リンク先で紹介されている方法が使えるかもしれません。なお、CopyTrans については Windows 向けのアプリだと思います。

- iPhone で連絡先を Google ドライブと同期
- CopyTrans Contacts を使って PC にバックアップ

[iPhoneの連絡先をバックアップする方法](https://www.copytrans.jp/support/iphone%E3%81%AE%E9%80%A3%E7%B5%A1%E5%85%88%E3%82%92%E3%83%90%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF%E3%82%A2%E3%83%83%E3%83%97%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E6%96%B9%E6%B3%95/)